# How to take branch specifier as user input along with other hard coded branch specifiers

Tags: jenkins

I have provided branch specifiers as shown in below image. If I remove the branch specifier with $BRANCH in it, job works perfectly(gets triggered) as anyone commits to develop or feature branches.

[image]

Now I also want that same job should also be able to build the project on any specific branch of choice. So I added a branch specifier and put $BRANCH in it. I have defined BRANCH as a string parameter and the user can give branch value as input when triggering the job manually.

But in this scenario even if the user gives a "bugfix112" job is still building develop branch. Or if earlier poll action had built the job on feature branch than even after providing user-input, the job will still build feature branch.

It seems like manual input has no effect. How can I configure a Jenkins job that can be triggered on poll SCM and also with user input for the branch parameter?

i also tried giving */$BRANCH,*/${BRANCH} but no success.

Answer (score 0):

So I had raised above issue with Jenkins git plugin author and it looks that for the above scenario we have to use the multi-branch pipeline. In fact, I agree with the statement.

https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-61074